# Issue in mac os for download pdf file

Tags: safari

May  i know what is the use of this symbol,

[image]

Comment: seem like `Download`.

Comment: But, i checked in browserstack, when i clicked, nothing happen @pezy

Comment: Your title is wrong, you use Safari in Windows, not MacOSX. This is an issue for Safari in Windows.

Comment: no, i am testing in http://www.browserstack.com for  OS X Yosemite Beta os.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a download button.

But it will not ask for a filename (as many other browsers would), but just download it to the default download directory. After clicking the download button, choose menu `View` > `Show Downloads` to see the downloaded file. After the shown filename, there will be a small "mignifying glass" icon, clicking this should show the file in the Finder (Mac OS X's Explorer equivalent).
To change he default download location, choose menu `Safari` > `Preferences…`. In the "General" tab, there is an entry labelled "Save downloaded files to:" where the default download location can be seen and changed.